# Proper way for contract to payout ether to addresses if conditions are met

Tags: solidity

I've got a contract that I'm building in ethereum-studio. I've sent some eth to the contract. And I want addresses to be able to query a function on the contract to see if they meet conditions in order to pull eth out of the contract. What is the proper way to do this in solidity?

Answer (score 3):

Make a function that returns true if the conditions are met. Mark it constant so you can get the return value from it without sending a transaction. Make a separate withdraw function that isn't marked constant but calls the first function to check if the conditions are met, then does the payout.